# get variables outside the for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, scope

I am trying to print all the values of x not just 9 outside the for loop. What change do I need to make to my code?

```
for x in range(10):
    x

print x
```

Comment: Put the print statement inside the for loop

Comment: putting inside just prints 9. I want to print all values 1 to 9.

Comment: Your current code has the print statement on the outside of the for loop so it is only printing the last value of x = 9. Putting the print statement inside the for loop will print each iteration of the loop...

Comment: Peter, you are missing the point of my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in:

```
vars = []
for i in range(10):
  vars.append(i)
for i in vars:
  print i
```

out:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: this is outside of the for loop.. in another for loop

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier just to do `print(range(10))`, but you could also do:

```
aux = []
for x in range(10):
    aux.append(x)

print(aux)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
for x in range(10):
    print(x+"\n")
```

the output will be

```
0

1

...

9
```

or

```
for x in range(10):
    print(x+end=' ')
```

out

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

:)